# lsb for Linux 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I tried to install logmein Hamachi for Linux but since .deb files do not work anymore, I tried to install it via the .tgz file and it seemed to work until I really got to the installation part.

When I type in:

`pimmulder@PimPC:~/Desktop/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-x64$ ./install.sh`

It says:

```
LogMeIn Hamachi needs lsb package
```

Maybe someone could help me.

Comment: .deb not working indicates a serious problem and installing from .tgz is not likely to help. Back up, what error are you getting with the .deb ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but my apache won't restart due to an lsb issue since upgrading to 16.04

Comment: 16.04 software center has issue installing debs but manual way with dpkg -i works. Have you tried that ?

Comment: dpkg -i isn't working it says: Selecting previously unselected package logmein-hamachi.
(Reading database ... 198671 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.139-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking logmein-hamachi (2.1.0.139-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of logmein-hamachi:
 logmein-hamachi depends on lsb-core (>= 3.0); however:
  Package lsb-core is not installed. Next comment

Comment: dpkg: error processing package logmein-hamachi (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 logmein-hamachi

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of Hamachi no longer requires lsb at all.

"[[Hamachi] can now be installed without [the] LSB package.](http://vpn.net/linux)"

Answer (score 0):

You need **lsb-core** to solve this problem, but this package is not available to direct install on 16.04.
I had a similar problem, and i've downloaded and installed the lsb-core package for Ubuntu 14.04, and it works.

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main" && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lsb-core
-y
```